# No smoothing using UnicodeFont

Tags: java, lwjgl, slick2d

I am attempting to draw a string using `Slick2D`'s `UnicodeFont`. Unfortunately it looks

[image: ugly]

Is there anyway to make it look nicer (with smoothing or antialiasing)? Here is my code

```
GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND);
GL11.glLoadIdentity();
GL11.glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 1, -1);
GL11.glMatrixMode(GL11.GL_MODELVIEW);

UnicodeFont f = new UnicodeFont(new Font("Consolas", Font.PLAIN, 18));
f.addAsciiGlyphs();
ColorEffect e = new ColorEffect();
e.setColor(java.awt.Color.green);
f.getEffects().add(e);
try {
    f.loadGlyphs();
} catch (SlickException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}

f.drawString(x, y, "UGLY");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable blending by writing `GL11.glEnable(GL11.GL_BLEND)` and `GL11.glBlendFunc(GL11.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL11.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)`.